# Boolean algebra - subtraction and inverse doubt

Tags: boolean-algebra

How to simultaneously solve these boolean expressions?

A' + AB = 0

AB = AC

AB + AC' + CD = C'D

where ' means conjugate.

So this might seem silly but:

a) I have never heard of **subtraction** in Boolean.

b) I have never heard of **inverse** (NOTE: Not to be confused with conjugate).

So, what I want to say is that if both "subtraction" and"inverse" DON'T exist in Boolean, how exactly does one solve above equations?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Where is "subtraction" ?

Comment: That is what I mean - without subtraction (which doesn't exist in Boolean) how do I solve these equations?

Comment: Start from the first one : $A'+BC= 0$. There is only one way that the sum of two elements is $0$ : when both are $0$.

Comment: If $A'=0$, then $A=1$. And so on...

Comment: Got it so my solution came out as: (A,B,C,D) = (1,0,0,1), is this correct?

Comment: Also I still feel that this is somewhat trial and error, how will it be done for larger questions (more equations - more variables)?